# Generic Spring controller

Tags: java, json, spring

I want to built a generic abstract controller for all my Spring controllers.
This controllers should have:

- UTF8 Encoding
- JSON reply with right content-type header.
- A common Json error handler

I tried this:

```
    public abstract class BaseController {

        @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
        @ResponseBody
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        public Return handleException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
          return new Return(ex);
        }
    }
```

This works for the json error handler, but I need other requirements so I tried to add this annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(produces = {"application/json; charset=UTF-8","*/*;charset=UTF-8"})
```

It fails and moreover the reply was not converted anymore into a json object but in a standard html view.

Comment: There's [`ControllerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) that lets you handle exceptions so you don't have to write that code in controllers.

Comment: Ok, with ControllerAdvice is possibile to make an exception for some controllers? (For example If I have a PDF report controller of type applacation/pdf, I cannot use a standard json error handler).

Comment: You may throw a custom exception for those and handle them with a specific business logic. Do same for other kind of exceptions as well like database or file management operations exceptions.

Comment: This option cannot be ovverride by specific ExceptionHandler of each controller?

Comment: You can through specific exceptions and intercept every thrown exception on a `ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: This can be a workaround... not a so clear solution.